# aws s3 allow access to bucket prefix for cognito user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have the following setup:

user logs in with cognito. He should now be able to use an s3 item url as the src of an html5 video.

```
<video src='http://aws.s3.somebucket/userId/videoId.mp4' />
```

I have managed to use the sdk for the login and now have the authorization token on the client. How do I setup the bucket to allow access to the directory matching the userId, and how can I trigger/pass the authorization token?

Comment: Are you using Cognito User Pools? Or Cognito Federated Identity?

Comment: @RobDevereux user Pools

Answer (score 0):

You should integrate your user pool with Federated identities following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html).

Setup the identity pool for S3 access following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html).

After this you will get AWS credentials which would allow the user to only access based on the identityId.